# После передачи файла, файл перестаёт работать

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyinstaller, kali-linux

Написал программу на питоне, после чего через pyinstaller сделал её исполняемым файлом. Хотел перекинуть этот файл на другую машину, использовал яндекс диск. Но программа работает только на машине, на которой я её писал, на других не работает - `bash: ./test: Permission denied`

У меня есть две версии возникновения проблемы:

1. Разные системы. Я перекидывал файл с Ubuntu на Kali
2. Отсутствие нужных библиотек. В программе используются библиотеки, которые есть на первой машине, но нет на второй.

Хотелось бы узнать причину возникновения проблемы и её решение.

Comment: можно попробовать по классике, вначале сделать `chmod u+x test`, а потом запустить `./test`

Comment: ну да, скачанный с яндекс-диска файл сам по себе не становится исполняемым...

Comment: Помимо вышесказанного, ЯД может по наивности преобразовывает `\n` в `\r\n`, считая, что это текстовый файл.

Comment: там ещё много вариантов. Например, внутри запускается какая то программа, которая не хочет без прав админа запускаться на Кали